# Will The Bat overwrite old mailbox files if I point new installation to their location?

Tags: installation, email-client, the-bat

I am installing new version of [`The Bat`](https://www.ritlabs.com/en/) and wishing it use the same mail database as previous version.

During installation I get a configuration window:

[image]

I vaguely remember, that many years ago I did it, it wiped out all of my files. Either because different version or because of general stupidity.

How to know will it happen or not?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what the window reads. Have you made a backup of the database? If so, you should be OK to attempt the upgrade. For specifics, you should contact Ritlabs support.

Comment: I made a backup but also tried different directory. Now I saw from program behavious, that it probably would work well, but can't force it to ask again :)

Comment: Does the program have an import feature? If so, use that to import your data.

Comment: I just wired from old directory to new one, which made a desogranization. Now I wish to get rid of new directory!

Answer (score 0):

1. **Right-click** an existing mail account and select "**Properties**"
2. In the popup window, select the 4th entry "**Files and Folder**"
3. The first text field in the right panel tells you the folder where your database is stored.
4. Using Windows file explorer, navigate to the parent folder and **rename the folder** that stores your existing mail database (so that it won't be overwritten).
5. After installing TheBAT!, in the "**Tools**" menu, select "**Import messages**", which will let you **import message from the ".TBB" files** that are within the subfolders of your backuped mail database (IMAP, Outbox, Sent, Trash, ...).